# Changed break-pads - wipers don't work, ABS malfunctioning?

Tags: abs, windshield-wipers, service

A week ago on Friday I took my car (Fiat Grande Punto 2008, 1.3, 55kW) to the car service to change my front break pads as there were worn out. Yesterday there was heavy rain and I had to do a sudden hard breaking in a turn and as a stomped on the break my car started to break intermittently. It started to apply the break then it stopped and it did that until full stop (which took 2-3 seconds).

This was the only hard stop in the rain I did since the break-pad change. I'm assuming that this is when the ABS kicked in? I did hard breaks before but nothing so hard that the ABS kicks in. Could this be a problem with break-pad installation or the break-pads them self? I did HARD stop a few weeks ago (so much that the seat belt lock engaged) and everything was fine. I did a test drive and everything works when I'm breaking *normally*. Should I test it with hard breaking?

Additionally, my windshield wipers don't work. In the car user manual I couldn't find the wiper motors fuse. (Are wipers on a single fuse in this car?) Could this be related? I also haven't used them since the service (I used them just before the service). Is it possible that the service technician messed something up?

Also is it normal for a fuse not to have voltage on them even with the ignition key turned? There are two fuses under the hood that have no power on both pins.

EDIT: The wipers seems to be working now.

Comment: Changing the front brake *pads* seems strange. Since asbestos brake pads were discontinued, the brake *discs* usually wear down below their minimum thickness before the pads wear out. But in any case, there is no reason to touch *anything* to do with the car electrics, when changing discs or pads.

Comment: @alephzero curious, I find that 1 set of discs will go through 2 or 3 sets of pads before getting to be below the minimum thickness...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Don't take any chances where your brakes are concerned. There's a real chance of death or serious injury if they don't work as intended.

There are people here entirely qualified to give advice, im certain, but ultimately they're strangers on the internet with no accountability.

Get it straight to a garage - ideally a different one from where the work was done.

The above said: braking hard on a corner in the wet is where ABS is likely to step in, as well as other electronic aids.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about brakes are, if they are installed properly you will know. If they are not, you will also know.

So here is a brief explanation of how the ABS system works.
It monitors independent wheel speed. In the event that 1 wheel is not identical in speed to the rest, the system activates and it sounds and feels like you were driving on a rumble strip on the highway. It's this jarring pulsation on the pedal and this nasty noise that it creates. This is normal operation of the system, plus if your vehicle is modern enough to have an ABS system, it would detect any troubles with it and illuminate the trouble light if there were in fact any problems with the system. Yes this is not always the case but given the information we can safely surmise this is normal operation given how the system acted in the appropriate scenario.

the motor that activates the ABS system pluses hundreds of times per SECONDS. each time you feel a pulse its the motor turning on and off faster than you could possibly count.

As far as your wiper concern you need to determine the exact definition of the fuses, some manufactures provide pictures that sometimes leave room for interpretation (looking at you Europe).

Japanese and North America is good with its pictures because it also gives a word of what it is. Call your local dealer and ask them nicely if they can show you where the wiper fuse is. 
If calling doesn't work, show up and ask a service advisor. The best way to get what you want is to be extremely polite to them and make them aware that you may be wasting their time but you are really sorry and just need a quick question answered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You mention that the pulses are hundreds of times per second. But what actually happened was that it pulsated 5 or 6 times in those 2-3 seconds of breaking. It felt more like I was manually pressing and releasing the break (pumping action). Could that be a normal behavior in my situation?